# store values of an object in a variable

Tags: jquery, object, each

I'm trying to store all the dataids of an object whose packageid is equal to 9, please take a look at my code on jfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tcwgf/

this doesn't seem to return anything:

```
 $("h2").html(dataids);
```

Comment: Using JS fiddle is a very good thing, and highly welcome, but please add the code here too!

Comment: Why do you have both `catalogue` and `localproducts`?  You're making `localproducts` into an array of objects, then pushing that array into `catalogue`.  So when you loop over `catalogue`,  you need to loop twice, so you loop over the inner array too.

Answer (score 1):

You push objects in `localproducts` and then push whole this array in `catalogue`. So this last array have 1 item which contains array.

As I understand your code, you can drop `localproducts` array and push directly to `catalogue`

http://jsfiddle.net/Tcwgf/2/

```
catalogue.push({ ... });

...

$(catalogue).each(function(){  
  if (this.packageid == 3) dataids.push(this.dataid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but you might want to look into this : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

You could find your packageid 9 with it and then display what you want to display, right now with $("h2").html(dataids); you're trying to display an array, which might explain why things aren't working right ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you fully or not, but I think this is what you were aiming for.  If not please explain more.  Using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) with .get(), you can get an array of your custom object..

```
var store_products = function () {
  // get all li's that have a span.packageid with 9 as the text
  var $lis = $('span.packageid').filter(function(i,v){
       return $.trim($(v).text()) == 9;
  }).closest('li');  

  // get an array of objects properties you defined
  var x = $lis.map(function(i,v){
    var $itm = $(v);
    return {
         'dataid' : $itm.attr('data-id'), 
         'datapackage' : $itm.attr('data-package'), 
         'packageid' : $itm.children('.packageid').text()
    };
  }).get();

  // Now variable x is an array of the objects with packageid = 9
  console.log(x);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Prqkb/)